# If-directive macro comparison

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Why is the `#if` condition in the following code fulfilled:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define VALUE foo    

int main() {    
#if VALUE == bar
    std::cout << "WORKS!" << std::endl;
#endif // VALUE
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [page on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional) states:

> After all macro expansion and evaluation of defined and __has_include
>   (since C++17) expressions, any identifier which is not a boolean
>   literal is replaced with the number ​0​ (this includes identifiers
>   that are lexically keywords, but not alternative tokens like and).

So `VALUE` is first replaced with `foo`, and then both `foo` and `bar` are replaced with 0.

Comment: What about C++98,C++03, C++11 and C++14?

Comment: @kelalaka It's all the same. It's been that way ever since C89.

Comment: @kelalaka The "since C++17" only refers to the "and __has_include" part. Before C++17 it was the same, just with that part omitted.

Answer (score 17):

This is because neither `foo` nor `bar` have been given any definition or value - so they are the same (i.e. replaced with a "0" value). Compilers will give warnings about this.

The `MSVC` compiler (Visual Studio 2019) gives the following:

> warning C4668: 'foo' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing
>   with '0' for '#if/#elif'
>   warning C4668: 'bar' is not defined as a preprocessor
>   macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif'

So `VALUE` is given the value '0' (default for `foo`) and `bar` also has '0', so `VALUE == bar` evaluates to "TRUE."

Similarly, `clang-cl` gives the following:

> warning : 'foo' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
>  warning
>   : 'bar' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]

Comment: Does the warning mandatory or it is a feature of the compilers?

Comment: @kelalaka  To the best of my knowledge, no compiler 'warnings' are mandatory! Even with the `MSVC` and `clang-cl` compilers, this warning can be disabled (either specifically, or by setting an appropriate warning 'level').

Answer (score 16):

In a `#if` statement, any identifier that remains after macro substitution (except for `true` and `false`) are replaced with the constant `0`.  So your directive becomes

```
#if 0 == 0
```

which is true.

Comment: To clarify, '#define VALUE foo' defines the symbol 'VALUE' to resolve to the same value as the symbol 'foo', but the symbol 'foo' has no meaning, so it will be interpreted as 0.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you are after, try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#define DEBUG  

int main() {    
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "WORKS!" << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

In this case you can turn the debugging statements off by changing the "define" to "undef".

```
#include <iostream>
#undef DEBUG  

int main() {    
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "WORKS!" << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

You might find that your compiler allows you to define DEBUG outside the code itself, at which point you can reduce the code to

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {    
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "WORKS!" << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

And then invoke the compiler with an option such as -DDEBUG=0

Check out the chapter on Defensive Programming in Steve McConnell, "Code Complete."