# I'm writing a driver for ADC (AVR microcontroller) for some reason conditional directives #if doesn't accept #define macros in this way (strings)

Tags: c, embedded

for some reason conditional directives #if doesn't accept #define macros in this way (putting strings in macros) the workaround I found is to put numbers instead, although it accepts enabled and disabled as a string, anyone can explains that please also is there a right way to put 2 conditional statements (#if condition_1 && condition_2) or it has to be nested #if directive?

```
#ifndef _ADC_CONFIG_H_
#define _ADC_CONFIG_H_
#define Auto_Trigger            Enabled       //Bit 5 – ADATE: ADC Auto Trigger Enable
/*
ADTS2 ADTS1 ADTS0 Trigger Source
Put the selection number (0 to 7)
0- Free_Running_mode
1- Analog_Comparator
2- External_Interrupt_Request_0
3- Timer_Counter0_Compare_Match
4- Timer_Counter0_Overflow
5- Timer_Counter_Compare_Match_B
6- Timer_Counter1_Overflow
7- Timer_Counter1_Capture_Event
*/
#define ADC_AUTO_TRIG           Analog_Comparator

#include "ADC_config.h"
#if Auto_Trigger == Enabled && ADC_AUTO_TRIG == Free_Running_mode
    SFIOR &= ADC_TRIG_SOURCE_MASK;   //clear the last 3 bits SFIOR register
    SFIOR |= 0;
#elif Auto_Trigger == Enabled && ADC_AUTO_TRIG == Analog_Comparator
    SFIOR &= ADC_TRIG_SOURCE_MASK;
    SFIOR |= 1;
#elif Auto_Trigger == Enabled && ADC_AUTO_TRIG == 2
    SFIOR &= ADC_TRIG_SOURCE_MASK;
    SFIOR |= 2;
#elif Auto_Trigger == Enabled && ADC_AUTO_TRIG == 3
    SFIOR &= ADC_TRIG_SOURCE_MASK;
    SFIOR |= 3;
#elif Auto_Trigger == Enabled && ADC_AUTO_TRIG == 4
    SFIOR &= ADC_TRIG_SOURCE_MASK;
    SFIOR |= 4;
#elif Auto_Trigger == Enabled && ADC_AUTO_TRIG == 5
    SFIOR &= ADC_TRIG_SOURCE_MASK;
    SFIOR |= 5;
#elif Auto_Trigger == Enabled && ADC_AUTO_TRIG == 6
    SFIOR &= ADC_TRIG_SOURCE_MASK;
    SFIOR |= 6;
#elif Auto_Trigger == Enabled && ADC_AUTO_TRIG == 7
    SFIOR &= ADC_TRIG_SOURCE_MASK;
    SFIOR |= 7;
#else
#error "Wrong selection"
#endif
```

Comment: You'll need #define statements for `Free_Running_Mode` and others, like `#define Free_Running_Mode 0`. Otherwise, the compiler won't (can't) know what those are.

Comment: Note that the preprocessor will consider the values of undefined macros to be zero (IIRC - at least, [that's the case for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60779170/10871073)).

Comment: The core of the problem is that `==` will only compare integers. It does not work with string. That's why @AdrianMole is saying you need more defines.

Comment: 1) You are not comparing **strings**, you are comparing **undefined symbols**. 2) As others pointed out, the preprocessor can only compare numbers. 3) Undefined symbols are replaced by zero by the preprocessor.

Comment: Also, long conditional preprocessor chunks like this is rarely ever the correct way to implement something. Consider using a look-up table in run-time or such.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `#if` typically treats all symbols which are not `#defined` as 0. Macros that are defined as "empty" are also treated as 0.

This means that the following lines:

```
#define Auto_Trigger            Enabled
#define ADC_AUTO_TRIG           Analog_Comparator
...
#if Auto_Trigger == Enabled && ADC_AUTO_TRIG == Free_Running_mode
```

... are interpreted as:

```
#define Auto_Trigger
#define ADC_AUTO_TRIG
...
#if 0 == 0 && 0 == 0
```

... unless you have `#defined` the macros `Enabled` and `Analog_Comparator` somewhere.

You **MUST** explicitly add the following lines before the first `#define` or `#if` that uses the constants:

```
#define Enabled            123
#define Analog_Comparator  456
#define Free_Running_mode  789
...
```

You cannot use "strings" as you tried to do it.